# Why are the dot products in this expression not evaluating (after substituting Symbols for BaseVectors in CoordSys3D)?

Tags: python, sympy, physics

The below expression looks messy, but all that needs to be known is that:

1. All of the variables are of type *Symbol*
2. Dot products were formed with *sp.vector.dot*
3. Absolute value performed with *sp.Abs*

[image: Expression consisting entirely of Symbols.]

The issue arises in this second_expression below, where I have simply used *first_expression.subs()* to sub *two* *Symbols* for *BaseVectors* from the *CoordSys3D* framework. Namely, the **z hat** and **e_ j** symbols from above have been swapped for **k_N** and **j_N** respectively shown below.

[image: Expression with three symbols swapped for BaseVectors from CoordSys3D framework.]

Issue: **The three dot products are not evaluating** (and neither is the Abs). Why would it not evaluate when *sympy.vector.dot* is designated to dot two *BaseVectors*? (the orthogonal **k_N** and **j_N**).

The second expression should look like this when evaluated:

[image]

If anyone is willing to help me with this in any way, I would be *extremely* grateful.

**EDIT:** This problem has been condensed into a simpler one
[SymPy substitute Symbol for Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844801/sympy-substitute-symbol-for-vector)

Comment: what's the code like?

Comment: I expect that you've ended up with something like `Add` rather than `VectorAdd`. It's not possible to tell that from the images shown though

Comment: The issue is indeed what you say, but with `Mul` and `VectorMul` in the case of individual dot products.

A term that should be a `VectorMul` (after substituting a `Symbol` for a `BaseVector`) is instead just a `Mul`. Do you know a fix to this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844801/sympy-substitute-symbol-for-vector