# SymPy substitute Symbol for Vector

Tags: python, sympy

I have an expression of type `Mul` called `term` in the code below. Within `term` is a type `Symbol` called `zhat`. I want to perform something like `term.subs(zhat, vec)` where `vec` is of type `BaseVector`. I am subbing a symbol for a vector. The output is assigned to `out_actual` in the code.

The issue is that `out_actual` is of type `Mul` when I need it to be of type `VectorMul`. The variable `out_ideal` is what I would expect from the substitution. Any way to obtain `out_ideal`?

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
N = CoordSys3D('N')
Q, eps, zhat = sp.symbols('Q \epsilon_0 \\hat{\\mathbf{z}}')

vec = N.k
term = Q*eps*zhat
out_ideal = Q*eps*vec
out_actual = term.subs(zhat, vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly pleasant or generalizable, but you could do the following to convert any `Mul` into a `VectorMul` whenever appropriate (and leaving it as a `Mul` otherwise):

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
from sympy.core.mul import Mul

N = CoordSys3D('N')

def multiply_args(obj):
    '''Gets the result of multiplying all of the Mul's args together.'''
    if not isinstance(obj, Mul):
        raise ValueError('Input must be an instance of Mul')
    args = obj.args
    prod = args[0]
    for e in args[1:]:
        prod = prod * e
    return prod

Q, eps, zhat = sp.symbols('Q \epsilon_0 \\hat{\\mathbf{z}}')
vec = N.k

term = Q*eps*zhat
sub_result = term.subs(zhat, vec)
sub_result = multiply_args(sub_result)
```

The reason this is necessary is that `subs`, a method which belongs to the `Basic` class, simply looks at all of the arguments (e.g. `Q`, `eps`, `zhat`) of the `Mul` object (`term`) and replaces each that matches the substitution target, and gives the result as a `Mul` but with an amended list of `args` (i.e. `zhat` has been replaced with `vec`). It doesn't do any further evaluation on the result, and leaves the argument as a `Mul`.

To convert it to a `VectorMul`, you can just multiply the resulting arguments together manually, like you did to get `out_ideal`. All `multiply_args` does is manually multiplies the arguments together, which then promotes to a `VectorMul` if any of the arguments is a `Vector`. Obviously this only works because you know you have started with a `Mul`; you'd need to generalize this to deal with other types if you needed to.

If could be worth putting in a feature reqeust to the SymPy Github repository for this functionality.